# Changing onClick value through radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am quite new to all this and wondering if someone can help with something. I have the code below which when the button is clicked is references a javascript file and populates a random english word. I am wanting to change it to add a radio button. The radio button will allow the user to select an english word or french word. How can I change my `onClick` command to use the value of the selected radio button?

```
<FORM NAME="Generator">  
    <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="WordBox" id="wordbox"><BR>
    <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Generate" onClick="English(document.WordForm);" id="button">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you've a function `English` that take the `form` as a only parameter, you don't have to change anything just add the `radio` and get the value from the form inside your function, like :

```
<FORM NAME="Generator">  
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="WordBox" id="wordbox">
    <BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="language" value="ENGLISH">ENGLISH
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="language" value="FRENCH">FRENCH
    <BR>
    <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Generate" onClick="English(document.WordForm);" id="button">
</FORM>
```

Then get the value :

```
function English(form){
     var language = form.language.value;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what it is that you're trying to achieve, but is it something along the lines of what I've created in this fiddle?

https://jsfiddle.net/pq6eh1jk/5/

HTML:

```
<input id="word" type="text"/>
<input id="english" type="radio" name="language" checked="checked"> English
<input type="radio" name="language" value="english"> French
<input type="button" onclick="generateText()" value="Generate Text"/>
```

JS:

```
var englishWordBank = [ 'Animal', 'Bank', 'City' ];
var frenchWordBank = [ 'Avion', 'Bonjour', 'Chat' ];

var generateText = function() {
    var wordInput = document.getElementById('word');
  var randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random()*2); //Between 0-2
    if (document.getElementById('english').checked)
    wordInput.value = englishWordBank[randomIndex];
  //French:
  else
    wordInput.value = frenchWordBank[randomIndex];
};
```